# PNG Image not showing up in PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, png, fpdf

I properly encoded my PNG image. It is a Grayscale, 8 bit. The image is 5100(w) x 6600(h). MediaBox is 5100.0 6600.0.

Image:

```
3 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /ImageB]
/XObject <<
/Im8 8 0 R
>>
>>
endobj


8 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Height 6600
/Width 5100
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 590065
>>
stream
....zlib compressed stream
```

Image transformation:

```
9 0 obj
<</Length 54>>
stream
q
5100 0 0 6600 0 0 cm
/Im8 Do
Q
endstream
endobj
```

Page:

```
10 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/CropBox [0.0 0.0 5100.0 6600.0]
/MediaBox [0.0 0.0 5100.0 6600.0]
/Resources 3 0 R
/Contents [  ]
>>
endobj
```

The image is not showing up. I verified pixel by pixel.

The stream consists of 33666600 (5100x6600 + 6600) bytes total. 6600 out of them indicate Predictor that was used. In my case it is /Predictor 13.

I write these 33666600 bytes, i.e. only compressed IDAT.

Perhaps coordinates?
Compression?
What am I missing here?

Comment: If your Contents is really `[ ]` (i.e. empty), how do think your image will be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check ISO-32000-1 (the PDF standard), you'll discover that PNG isn't supported in PDF. You're using the `/FlateDecode` filter, which means you tell the PDF viewer that the image is stored inside the PDF file as a compressed bitmap. If you store a compressed PNG, the PDF viewer won't know how to render it. (*update:* Your most recent update indicates that you do store the image as a bitmap.)

Also: in your page dictionary (object 10), you store the `/Contents` of the page as a PDF array, but that array is empty. It should be `[ 9 0 R ]`

In your code sample, you also forgot to copy/paste the `endstream` keyword.

Comment: @user3089422 If Bruno's hints don't help, please supply the full PDF (e.g. using some decent file sharing platform like drop box) for inspection.

Comment: I read the "Adobe Portable Document Format Version 1.4" document. I also generated the document per v4.

    0000000 045 120 104 106 055 061 056 064 015 045 200 231 242 243 015 012
              %   P   D   F   -   1   .   4  \r   % 200 231 242 243  \r  \n

I will try to fill out contents array

Comment: So this was resolved. As a side comment. PDF 1.4 support embedded PNG images. The trick is to know /FlateDecode parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone: I 've encountered a similar issue when trying to create pdf from HTML. Included png images were not being rendered into pdf (a small square appeared where the image was supposed to be). 
The solution in my case was to create the png (we used photoshop) having checked interlaced option.